# IoC/DI + "normal" constructor arguments mvvm

Tags: dependency-injection, mvvm, inversion-of-control

I am using unity in C# to achieve dependency injection and inversion of control.

What if I have a class, let's say a viewmodel, that depends on several services like a repository, a validator and a log BUT its also dependent on just a simple list of data
objects. So I would have a Constructor like this

```
ClientVM(DBService db, ClientValidator v, Log log, List<Client> clients)
```

The way I solved this at the moment is with a class that handles the creation of ClientVMs, I call it a factory, however after googling I'm not sure anymore if it is the right term.

```
public ClientFactory(DBService db, ClientValidator v, Log log) { ... }

public Client Create(List<Client> clients) {
    return new ClientVM(db, v, log, clients);
}
```

Then I can inject the ClientFactory everywhere I would need to create new ClientVMs.

This still feels somewhat clean to me. But what if I scale it up and say I have a detail viewmodel in my ClientVMs, their Adresses for example.

So my ClientVM depends now on an extra AdressVM, which would mean I write a similar AdressFactory, inject it into the ClientFactory and then in my create() method I call the 
AdressFactories Create() method.

It's starting to get messy. Maybe.

I am wondering if this is a sign of bad design? How would I do it simpler? Can I avoid all these "factories"? Is this just the way it is since I'm rather close to the composition root and creation logic is still somewhat complex?

Comment: Depends on your mvvm framework/implementation. For example in MvvmCross 'static' dependencies would be injected via constructor while parameters known at runtime would go into Prepare() method
https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle

Comment: Isn't that ClientFactory doing what Unity is already supposed to be doing for you?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is exactly how this problem should be solved. And it truly is called a Factory.
Yes, things get somehow messy when lots of dependencies are involved.

Some more advanced IoC containers, <del>like Unity</del>, can create these kind of factories automagically. Well, according to [Unity auto-factory with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825270/unity-auto-factory-with-params) , only Autofac can really do that out-of-the box. While Unity can do it, the setup seems to be not much different from defining your own class in terms of amount of code and complexity.